# how to perform calculations on dynamically added table rows in jquery

Tags: jquery

hi have a form which dynamically adds a table row on a button click but now i want to perform calculations into my table's columns like i have a colum name prevqty, thisqty, qty(which is total qty), rate and amount and i have a total field in which the total of amount is stored i have tried  a calculation but it doesnt seems to work

here is my script

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
var currentItem = $('#items').val();

$('#data').on('keyup', '.prevqty, .thisqty, .qty, .rate, .cal', calculateRow);

$('#addnew').click(function() {
    currentItem++;
    $('#items').val(currentItem);
    $('#data').append('<tr>\n\
        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="ord_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="return copy(this.val());"/></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="srno_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth"/></td>\n\
        <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_' + currentItem + '" cols="70" class="form-input-textareasm"></textarea></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="unit_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate"/></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="prevqty_' + currentItem + '" class="prevqty form-input-rate" onkeyup="calculateRow();"//></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="thisqty_' + currentItem + '" class="thisqty form-input-rate" onkeyup="calculateRow();"//></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="qty_' + currentItem + '" class="qty form-input-rate" onkeyup="calculateRow();"/></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="rate_' + currentItem + '" class="rate form-input-rate" onkeyup="calculateRow();"/></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="amt_' + currentItem + '" class="cal  form-input-amt" onkeyup="calculateRow();"/></td>\n\
        </tr>'
                     );
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".cal").each(function () {
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#total").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
function calculateRow() {
    var cost = 0;
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    var prevqty = parseFloat($row.find('.prevqty').val());
    var thisqty = parseFloat($row.find('.thisqty').val());
    var qty = parseFloat($row.find('.qty').val(prevqty + thisqty));
        //parseFloat($row.find('.qty').val());
    alert(qty);
    if (isNaN(qty)) {
        $row.find('.qty').val("0");
    } else {
        $row.find('.qty').val(qty);
    }
    // changed the following line to only look within the current row
    var rate = parseFloat($row.find('.rate').val());

    cost = qty * rate;

    if (isNaN(cost)) {
        $row.find('.cal').val("0");
    } else {
        $row.find('.cal').val(cost);
    }
    calculateSum();
}});
```

i have a working fiddle here  the prevqty and thisqty is working properly but the rate and amounts calculation is not working see here http://jsfiddle.net/rey_kahn/YS4N2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your `$("#addnew").click` event fires you will want to rebind the `keyup/calculateRow` method.  Something like:

```
$('#addnew').click(function() {
    currentItem++;
    $('#items').val(currentItem);
    $('#data').append('<tr>\n\
        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="ord_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="return copy(this.val());"/></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="srno_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth"/></td>\n\
        <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_' + currentItem + '" cols="70" class="form-input-textareasm"></textarea></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="unit_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate"/></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="prevqty_' + currentItem + '" class="prevqty form-input-rate" onkeyup="calculateRow();"//></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="thisqty_' + currentItem + '" class="thisqty form-input-rate" onkeyup="calculateRow();"//></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="qty_' + currentItem + '" class="qty form-input-rate" onkeyup="calculateRow();"/></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="rate_' + currentItem + '" class="rate form-input-rate" onkeyup="calculateRow();"/></td>\n\
            <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="amt_' + currentItem + '" class="cal  form-input-amt" onkeyup="calculateRow();"/></td>\n\
        </tr>'
                     );
    $('#data').off('keyup').on('keyup', '.prevqty, .thisqty, .qty, .rate, .cal', calculateRow);
});
```

Notice that `$("#data").off('keyup').on(...` at the end of the event?  That should keep your new rows calculating correctly.

**UPDATE**

After reviewing the code you posted in your jsfiddle comment, I found a few HTML errors but I think the real problem was the way you were setting/calculating `qty`.  Check out this update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YS4N2/1/

There you will see I set the qty input separate from how it is used for the purposes of calculation.  This works ok.

Comment: After reviewing the code again, I wonder why you bind `keyup` with jQuery then again have `onkeyup` calls in each `input` element, all calling the same calculateRow() method. Why is that?

Comment: coz i need to call it everytym when a user ads an input to the feild

Comment: thnks sir but did u notice that when a user enters a value in prevqty the value of totqty goes to NaN instead of 0

Comment: yeah that looks like another problem with your logic.  Should be easy to fix if you do some more testing around your variables

Comment: yup but for now thnks alot sir

Answer (score 0):

Added Default Row at the beginning and Grand Total .

And some minor changes.

```
<table border="1px" width="90%" id="data">                  
              <tr>
                 <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Order</font><span></span></label></td>
                 <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Sr No.</font><span></span></label></td>
                 <td width="580px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Description</font><span></span></label></td>
                 <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Unit</font><span></span></label></td>
                 <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Previous Qty.</font><span></span></label></td>
                 <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">This Bill Qty</font><span></span></label></td>
                 <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Total Quantity</font><span></span></label></td>
                 <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Rate</font><span></span></label></td>
                 <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Amount</font><span></span></label></td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
                <td><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="ord_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="return copy(this.val());"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="srno_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth"/></td>     
                <td><textarea name="descrip_' + currentItem + '" cols="70" class="form-input-textareasm"></textarea></td>     
                <td><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="unit_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate"/></td>     
                <td><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="prevqty_' + currentItem + '" class="prevqty "/></td>     
                <td><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="thisqty_' + currentItem + '" class="thisqty "/></td>     
                <td><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="qty_' + currentItem + '" class="qty "/></td>     
                <td><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="rate_' + currentItem + '" class="rate "/></td>     
                <td><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="amt_' + currentItem + '" class="cal"/></td>     
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="8"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="total"/></td>
              </tr>
```

Check UPDATED Link: http://jsfiddle.net/YS4N2/9/